# get all values from arraylist in php

Tags: php

I have arraylist like :  `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5];`
How can I get each of these values in php?
Is there any function ? I tried array() but it did not return anything.I really appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you provide more details? a bit of code maybe?

Comment: What's an "arraylist"? PHP doesn't have any such thing. What you have is already an array, you don't need to call `array()` on it.

Comment: If you have `$a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];` you can access the elements with `$a[0]`, `$a[1]`, and so on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let say your `$array = [1,2,3,4,5];`

To get the values:

```
foreach($array as $values):
      echo $values.'<br/>';
endforeach;
```

Or if you want based on elements, you can get by this way:

```
//To get value 1
echo $array[0];
// 0 being here the index of your array
// so echo $array[0] will output 1 since it's the first key of your array
```

Comment: I am sending those values from android to php so this value will be a string how can I convert it into array without explode() which also has brackets "[" ?

Comment: basically it has double quotes as I pass the variable as a string .Eg: `$a="[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]";`

Comment: Why you not pass it to JSON format instead of string og array? Its easy to manipulate...

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array like this

```
$numbers = array(1,2,3,4,5);
```

with five values (i.e indexed 0 - 4) you can print out all values in the array using the print_r() function like this:

```
print_r($numbers);
```

Or you can loop through every element in the array with any PHP looping statement like FOR STATEMENTS, FOREACH STATEMENTS, WHILE STATEMENTS..
e.g

```
foreach($numbers as $num){
echo $num;
echo '<br/>';
}
```

You can also get a single value from the array using the index for example my array has 5 values (indexed from 0 - 4) if i want to print out the number '3' i would write

```
echo $numbers[2];
```